# Couldn't find User with 'id'=true Omniauth - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am implementing omniauth for twitter and I have run into an error "Couldn't find User with 'id'=true" the error is pointing to the application controller `current_user` metho. Heere is my `current_user` method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

end
```

and here is my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_or_create_by_auth(auth_data)
    user = where(provider: auth_data[:provider], uid: auth_data[:uid]).first_or_create
    user.update(name: auth_data[:info][:name])
  end
end
```

and finally the `SessionController` is below:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_or_create_by_auth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = @user
    redirect_to products_path, notice: "logged in as "
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Goodbye!!"
  end
end
```

When I trying to log in the error pops and i can't get past login to load my index page.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem should be solved with following modification in `User.find_or_create_by_auth` method:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_auth(auth_data)
  # all previous code

  # you should return user from here
  # your current code returned true of false
  user
end
```

Also you should save `@user.id` in session, not full `@user` object:

```
session[:user_id] = @user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this, the issue was that i had deleted the previous authenticated twitter user in the db and i was trying to authenticate with the same credentials again on the app.

so what i did is create a new twitter app and use different keys to authenticate into my rails App... hoep this explains it thanks